# Can you double up reducing washers?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, conduit

I have a 1.25" opening in a junction box that I need to be 1/2".

Can I use a set of 1.25 to 3/4 **AND** a set of 3/4 to 1/2 stacked together to accomplish this (and meet code)?

Thanks you in advance for any input/advice or references to where this is covered in code!!!

Comment: they exist `1-1/4 x 1/2 Reducing Washer for Medium- and Thick-Wall Steel Conduit`

Answer (score 2):

They exist `1-1/4 x 1/2 Reducing Washer for Medium- and Thick-Wall Steel Conduit`

And are UL listed, thus permitted.
UL Listed, C-UL Listed, CSA Certified

Found [here](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/conduit-reducing-washers/) and other places

Instructions:

> Reduce the knockout size in an outlet box or enclosure so you can attach a different size of medium-wall (IMC) and thick-wall (rigid) steel conduit to it. **Two reducing washers are required per knockout.**

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not 100% sure on code for this. What I do know is I've seen electricians whose work I respect do it all the time on work that passes inspection. Personally I like to put them on both sides so I can better snug them down with a couple of lock rings.

Answer (score 0):

They probably won't fit. But your friendly neighborhood electrical supply will have exactly the reducing washer you need to do it in one.  Big box stores not so much, so don't have "big-box-itis" :)